# Can an Amazon Seller Make Me Pay for Items I didn't order but they mailed me for free

Tags: commerce, online

This is different from other question because

1. I always leave 5-Star reviews
2. I am one of few people who purchases clothing from this buyer (it is ladies ethnic clothes)
3. Return label was included

I have been purchasing clothes from a particular 3rd Party Seller through Amazon.com

I always leave positive reviews.

Few days ago I received free set of clothes from the seller and a return label (return label requires sender to pay shipping).

I thought this was a gift because I am a regular customer.

Just now I received another free set of clothes from the seller and a return label.

Is this a good-will gesture, i.e. give away past-season inventory to regular customers.

Or is it something else. Will the seller attempt to get me to pay, even though I never ordered the items.

How would the seller get me to pay? At most I can write a 5-Star review, but I am concerned this may open a can of worms.

Comment: You might also consider the possibility that the goods were sent to you by mistake, and contact the seller to ask.  As user6726 noted, you would still be legally entitled to keep the goods, but you might feel that you should return them for ethical reasons, or to preserve your good relationship with the seller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a retailer sends you something you didn't order, can you keep it?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17533/if-a-retailer-sends-you-something-you-didnt-order-can-you-keep-it)

Comment: Where are you?  Whether the goods belong to the seller or to you will depend on jurisdiction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We cannot guess what the seller will do, but the law is that [unsolicited merchandise is treated as a gift](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0181-unordered-merchandise).

Comment: Ok, this is what I wanted to know. The Law. I may wait a while till I write 5-star review, just to see if the seller will say or do anything.